# Finding correct methods in libraries

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I began learning how to use numpy/scipy/matplotlib, and other associated libraries. I quickly discovered that code I got from third party sources (books, wikipedia, etc) rarely ran correctly, mostly due to import errors.

An example of such would be the following (code acquired from wikipedia):

input:

```
>>> from numpy.random import normal,rand
>>> x = normal(size=200)
>>> plt.hist(x,bins=30)
>>> plt.show()
```

However when I tried to run it:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hist'
```

Now, I realize the core error here is a mismatch in imports. This occurred before and each time I google the error message, and find the correct import 'layer'. My primary question here is how do I figure out on my own where the correct import is located? I tried doing this on my own by exploring modules using the dir() function, but in the case of trying to find the function hist in the directories of plt, I was unable to. Am I just supposed to search every directory until I find the function I need?

Comment: Experience? plt usually comes from `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`; it's kind of an implicit convention.

Comment: Google `"plt.hist"`. You'll find lots of examples of the correct import statement, such as [this one from the docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hugh already gave you your answer, but I'm going to help you a little further by introducing you to some other common `import` conventions you may come across, in particular when working with the data analysis stack.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

Comment: Statsmodels should be imported `import statsmodels.api as sm`

Comment: Thanks Skipper, updated.